# creating your sound workshop

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, workflow, max-msp, reaktor

hò

time has come where I need to make a step further

goal is to have a sound workshop where I can create "any" sound that comes to mind

picture a carpentry...you have tools and you can shape a wood log into anything that pops into your head.

this obviously will take time..you know...know more and more you tools, possibilities, ingredients etc..and that's fine

my question now is about choosing the right "place as a starting point and start learning that extensively and throughout

after doing some research I've pointed 2 possible choices:

- Reaktor
- Max For Live

there are many posts regarding this "VS" but I wanted to hear some from you too..

my main direction is about games for now (that's my field)

and it could be extended to Gui sounds, sound effects of any kind, and designing musical instruments too..

the need for having a custom workshop is that I'm not satisfied by the sounds I hear out there.. they all tend to be either too "electronic", too big, too "this" or too "that"
I tend to be attracted by more organic sounds (synthesized of course, no samples) or at least sounds I've never been able to find in libraries etc..

I have all these sounds playing in my head and I have a reasonable amount of knowledge to know how I would build that particular sound.. 
so the next step is to choose into which carpentry I'll put my tent on and settle

Ableton Live is my Daw of choice for several reasons so Max could be THE consequent choice but I do not take this for granted as I'm still new to this and I'm open to any suggestion..

Comment: If you don't like synthetic sounding sounds then trying to synthesizing them isn't really a good idea... 

I do love synths on a near well obscene level, but there's a reason so many of us spend a pretty serious cash to get good microphones, converters and studios, and dedicate a lot of time searching for the perfect props. Imagine that you have this log that you mentioned - it could make wonderful bowls, handles and tables. But it would make really horrendous bronze statues, wrenches and electronic tubes.

Comment: hey @ChristianvanCaine! I like synthetic sounds! I do have my good analog stuff like good mics, preamps etc.. the only thing is that I want to gain more freedom in creating different unique palettes of sounds so I feel the need to extend my skills into such territory .. but rather using already made VSTs (which I constantly use) I'm curious and fascinated by the idea of building custom synths .. which can easily turn into some very simple stuff anyway .. like a workshop ... the freedom of shaping a sound the way you hear it in your head

Comment: Ah! Okay, then I understand :-)